# the most fundamental of the sciences

Tags: word-usage

> How close can physics—**the most fundamental of the sciences**—bring us to an understanding of the foundations of reality?

Source: Scientific American September 2019

Why not just "the most fundamental of sciences"? With the definite article, it seems to me that "the sciences" particularly refers to "the natural sciences", or the article serves as am emphasis. I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it correct. "The sciences" refers to all of the fields of science, or perhaps the fields of natural science specifically. "The most [fundamental](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fundamental#English)" means "the most essential" or "the most basic" (in the sense of "the foundation").

See also [this humorous webcomic](https://xkcd.com/435/) about "purity" in the sciences:

[image: xkcd "Purity" comic]